# Java "Paint" Application

Tags: java, arraylist, copy, shapes

I'm designing this Java program that acts similarly to paint, and while it's nearly finished, I need some help. My problems are:
The program is supposed to be able to  Copy, and Paste using a Clipboard. As you can see, I haven't been able to figure out how to do it with the Clipboard, so I made a substitute, which doesn't function 100% correctly. Could you please help me with the Clipboard?
the code that i wrote displays only 1 copied shape ...but don't displays many shapes...
i've tried with LinkedList,vector,ArrayList and nothing works
please advise!

**
A component that shows a scene composed of shapes.
**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;


public class SceneComponent extends JPanel {

   
    private final ArrayList<SceneShape> shapes;
    private SceneShape copiedShape;

    private ArrayList<SceneShape> copiedShapesList;

    
    public void add(SceneShape s) {

        shapes.add(s);
        s.setSelected(false);
        repaint();
    }

    public void copySelectedShapes() {
        for (SceneShape s : shapes) {

            copiedShape = s.copy();
          
            copiedShapesList.add(copiedShape);
            System.out.println("shapes copied number ===     " + copiedShapesList.size());

        }

    }

    public void pasteSelectedShapes() {

        shapes.addAll(copiedShapesList);
        System.out.println("shapes size ===     " + shapes.size());
        repaint();
}

    

    void selectAll() {
        for (SceneShape s : shapes) {
            s.setSelected(true);
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public void removeSelected() {
        shapes.removeIf(SceneShape::isSelected);
        repaint();
    }

    void deleteAll() {
        shapes.clear();
        repaint();
    }

    public SceneComponent() {
        shapes = new ArrayList<>();

        copiedShapesList = new ArrayList<>();

        setBackground(Color.white);

     
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    
        for (SceneShape s : shapes) {
            s.draw(g2);
            if (s.isSelected()) {
                s.drawSelection(g2);
            }
        }
    }

}

**
  A house shape.
 **


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

/**
 * A house shape.
 */
public class HouseShape extends SelectableShape {

    private int x, y;

    
    public HouseShape(int x, int y, int width) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
    }

   

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        Rectangle2D.Double base
                = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y + width, width, width);

        // The left bottom of the roof
        Point2D.Double r1
                = new Point2D.Double(x, y + width);
        // The top of the roof
        Point2D.Double r2
                = new Point2D.Double(x + width / 2, y);
        // The right bottom of the roof
        Point2D.Double r3
                = new Point2D.Double(x + width, y + width);

        Line2D.Double roofLeft
                = new Line2D.Double(r1, r2);
        Line2D.Double roofRight
                = new Line2D.Double(r2, r3);

        g2.draw(base);

        g2.draw(roofLeft);

        g2.draw(roofRight);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawSelection(Graphics2D g2) {
        Rectangle2D.Double base = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y + width, width, width);
        g2.fill(base);

    }

    public boolean contains(Point2D p) {
        return x <= p.getX() && p.getX() <= x + width
                && y <= p.getY() && p.getY() <= y + 2 * width;
    }

   

  
    private final int width;

    @Override
    public SceneShape copy() {
       int i=10;i=i+20;
        return new HouseShape(i, 100, 50);
    
    }
 
}

/***
the main program

**/
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class SceneEditor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final SceneComponent scene = new SceneComponent();

        JButton houseButton = new JButton("House");
        houseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            int i = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                scene.add(new HouseShape(i, 50, 50) {
                });
                i = i + 100;
            }
        });

        JButton selectButton = new JButton("delete All");
        selectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                scene.deleteAll();
            }
        });
        JButton selectAllButton = new JButton("select All");
        selectAllButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                scene.selectAll();

            }
        });

        JButton copyButton = new JButton("Copy");
        selectAllButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                scene.copySelectedShapes();

            }
        });

        JButton pasteButton = new JButton("Paste");
        pasteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                scene.pasteSelectedShapes();

            }
        });

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();

        buttons.add(houseButton);
        buttons.add(selectAllButton);

        buttons.add(selectButton);
        buttons.add(copyButton);
        buttons.add(pasteButton);

        frame.setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.add(scene, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setLocation(300, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}




the interface for the common methodes that must be implemented



import java.awt.*;

public interface SceneShape
{
    abstract  SceneShape copy();
   
   void draw(Graphics2D g2);
 
   void drawSelection(Graphics2D g2);
  
   void setSelected(boolean b);
   
   boolean isSelected();
 
}


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public  class SelectableShape implements SceneShape {

    Rectangle2D rectangle;
    Color color;
    protected Point upperLeft;

    public void setSelected(boolean b) {
        selected = b;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    

    private boolean selected = false;

    @Override
    public SceneShape copy() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void drawSelection(Graphics2D g2) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

  
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "which doesn't function 100% correctly"? The pasteSelectedShapes and copySelectedShapes methods look like they should work correctly, so is it just a selection issue? Or do you need to paste the shape in a different position?

Comment: I note that the only code that actually does anything with the draw method is the `HouseShape`, all the other shape objects you make have a blank `draw` method as we can see in the `SceneShape` interface. Shouldn't you create objects that extend `SceneShape` and override that `draw` method, otherwise `SceneShape` objects they will do nothing.

Comment: the code works but it copy only for 1 shape!

Comment: i want it copy all the selected shapes!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be caused by a typo when you create the button:

```
JButton copyButton = new JButton("Copy");
selectAllButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
//...
```

Note how you create a `copyButton` but then you add an action listener to the `selectAllButton`. To fix this you should use:

```
JButton copyButton = new JButton("Copy");
//Now creating an action listener for the correct button
copyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
//...
```

One way to debug an issue like this is to print more information to the console at each step, for example te following would have showed us that the `copySelectedShapes` method was never called, and working backwards you would be able to find the typo above:

```
public void copySelectedShapes() {
    //Ad print statement outside the loop so it works even if there are zero shapes
    System.out.println("Copy method called for " + shapes.size() + "shapes");
    for (SceneShape s : shapes) {
        copiedShape = s.copy();
        copiedShapesList.add(copiedShape);
        //Print out the shape toString ID
        System.out.println("Copied shape " + s.toString());
    }
}
```

Note: In your `SceneComponent` class you override the `add` method, however, the `JPanel` class already has an default add method used for adding new swing components, instead you should rename your `add` method to `addShape` like so:

```
//Method name changed to avoid issues
public void addShape(SceneShape s) {

    shapes.add(s);
    s.setSelected(false);
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: this is what i get in the console:                                                                           shapes list size===     3........
Copy method called for     3    shapes...............
Copied shape     SceneEditor$2$2@54cb9c4a
shapes copied List size ===     1
Copied shape     SceneEditor$2$2@47ce1dd7
shapes copied List size ===     2............
Copied shape     SceneEditor$2$2@3ec264a3.............
shapes copied List size ===     3..................
shapes size ===     6.............
copied shapes size ===     3.......i get only 2 copied shapes displayed!

Comment: Looks like it is working correctly accoring to the console. Are you creating 3 HouseShape objects and making a copy of them? Because if you are trying to make a copy of a `SelectableShape` or a `SceneShape` then nothing will happen because they don't have anything in their copy or draw methods.

Comment: Also,, when you use `return new HouseShape(i, 100, 50);` in your copy method, this will cause some shapes to sit directly on top of other shapes. So it won't look like the copy happened, even though it worked but it just drew the shape direectly on top of another shape.

Comment: i found the solution!          
for(int i=1;i<copiedShapesList.size();i++)copiedShapesList.get(i).translate(0,50);                  ....and i changed the copy() methode by:public SceneShape clone() {
  this.setSelected(false);
        return new CarShape(x, 50, 50);

    }